# linq null reference error with orderby but firstordefault works

Tags: c#, linq

I have the following code:

```cs
IEnumerable<VariantChild> children = src.Variants
    .Where(v => !v.ExcludeFromWebsite && !v.ExcludeFromEcommerce)
    .SelectMany(v => v.Children)
    .Where(c => c.Price > 0 && !c.ExcludeFromWebsite && !c.ExcludeFromEcommerce);

if (children.Any())
{
    VariantChild child  = children.OrderBy(c => c.Price).FirstOrDefault();  // this line is throwing a null reference error

    if (child != null)
    {
        dest.Price = child.Price;
    }
}
```

But it is throwing a null refence exception on the line highlighted.  If I remove the `orderby`, the code works so I thought it may be to do with the price being null - but it can't be as it is a double.

Having stepped through the code, the `.Any()` returns true, but if I change that to `.Count()`, I get the null exception

If I step through and check the children object - I can see the results view is null so shouldn't `.Any()` return false (although why does `FirstOrDefult()` return a variant child?

Anyone any ideas what is causing the null exception?

Here is a screenshot of the code as I stepped into it:

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Is it possible that one of the items in `children` is null?  Although that shouldn't cause `Count` to throw.

Comment: The querry runs twice, could it be something to do with `src`?. Try adding `ToList()` to materialize `children`.

Comment: I tried .tolist on the where but it just throws an exception @sinatr.  `src` is just the parent class the holds the variants property

Comment: Keep in mind there is deferred execution with enumerable. You seem to assume the problem is with the `OrderBy` but since that is the first time complete enumeration of the source enumeration is done the null reference exception can originate anywhere in the code that defines how `children` should look like (the fact that a `ToList()` also throws an exception indicates that the problem is not with `OrderBy` specifically but with your `LINQ` query.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Keep in mind that linq expressions are not evaluated when created but only when necessary (ex: `ToList`, or in your case, `OrderBy` then `FirstOrDefault`. See [deferred execution](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/linq/deferred-execution-example).). So the null reference exception can be in the evaluation of `children`.

Supposing that `ExcludeFromWebsite` and `ExcludeFromEcommerce` are booleans and can't be null and `Price` is a double and can't be null. Only remain `Children` witch is an `IEnumerable` (because used in `SelectMany`) so it can be null.

Furthermore, in your screen shot, the stack trace refer to the `SelectManyIterator`.

You should check for `Children` to not be null :

```
IEnumerable<VariantChild> children = src.Variants
  .Where(v => !v.ExcludeFromWebsite && !v.ExcludeFromEcommerce)
  .SelectMany(v => v.Children ?? Enumerable.Empty<T>()) // T is the type of element in Children
  .Where(c => c.Price > 0 && !c.ExcludeFromWebsite && !c.ExcludeFromEcommerce);
```

Comment: This is it - the selectmany was null - I put a  `v.Children?.Any() == true` in the where clause above the select many and it has worked.  Thanks!

Comment: My implementation avoid double iteration, it's a good practice if the 'Enumerable' evaluation is a time or memory consuming task.